# Central difference formula

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, numerical-methods

For $h > 0$ consider the central difference formula

$$D(x_0) = \frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0-h)}{2h} \approx f'(x_0).$$
If $f \in C^3[x_0-h, x_0+h]$, then one can show that $$|f'(x_0) - D(x_0)| \leq \frac{M}{6}h^2, \quad \text{where} \quad M = \max_{x_0 - h \leq x \leq x_0 + h} f'''(x).$$

Namely, use Taylor's formula with the Lagrange form of the remainder:

$$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) + \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(x_0 + \theta_1 h),$$
$$f(x_0 - h) = f(x_0) - h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) - \frac{h^3}{6} f'''(x_0 + \theta_2 h),$$
with $0 < \theta_1, \theta_2 <1$. By taking the difference of the two expressions, dividing by $2h$ and rearranging, one arrives at

$$
\frac{f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0-h)}{2h} -f'(x_0) = \frac{h^2}{12}(f'''(x_0 + \theta_1 h)+f'''(x_0 + \theta_2 h))
$$
which yields the result.

Now my question concerns another proof  that I have come across which considers
 $$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) + r_3,$$
$$f(x_0 - h) = f(x_0) - h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) - R_3.$$
Then the claim is that

$$r_3 = \frac{1}{6} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} (f''(x) - f''(x_0))(x_0 + h - x) dx,$$
$$R_3 = \frac{1}{6} \int_{x_0}^{x_0 - h} (f''(x) - f''(x_0))(x_0 - h - x) dx.$$

Could someone clarify why this is so and why does it yield the result?

---

EDIT:
I tried to proceed using the formula derived by [Lutzl](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/115115/lutzl)

So we have

$$f(x_0 + h) = f(x_0) + h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) + r_3,$$
$$f(x_0 - h) = f(x_0) - h f'(x_0) + \frac{h^2}{2} f''(x_0) - R_3,$$

with

$$r_3 = \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} (f''(x) - f''(x_0))(x_0 + h - x) dx,$$
$$R_3 = \int_{x_0}^{x_0 - h} (f''(x) - f''(x_0))(x_0 - h - x) dx.$$

Consider the difference

\begin{align} 
&f(x_0 + h) - f(x_0 - h) - 2h f'(x_0)
\\ &= \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} (f''(x) - f''(x_0))(x_0 + h - x) dx + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 - h} (f''(x) - f''(x_0))(x_0 - h - x) dx
\\ &= \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'''(\xi (x))(x - x_0)(x_0 + h -x) dx + \int_{x_0}^{x_0 - h} f'''(\eta (x))(x - x_0)(x_0 - h - x) dx
\\ &= \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} f'''(\xi (x))(x - x_0)(x_0 + h -x) dx + \int_{x_0 - h}^{x_0} f'''(\eta (x))(x - x_0)(x + h - x_0) dx
\end{align}

Now divide by $2h$ and take the absolute value

\begin{align}
&\left|\frac{f(x_0+h) - f(x_0 - h)}{2h} - f'(x_0)\right| 
\\ &\leq \frac{1}{2h} \left[ \int_{x_0}^{x_0 + h} M h (x_0 + h -x)dx + \int_{x_0 -h}^{x_0} M h (x + h -x_0)dx \right]
\\ &= \frac{M}{2} \left[  \frac{h^2}{2} + \frac{h^2}{2}\right] = \frac{M}{2} h^2
\end{align}

So the esitmate is $\frac{M}{2} h^2$ unlike the initial  $\frac{M}{6} h^2$. Does this seem right?

Comment: It might be helpful to look into Taylor's theorem where the remainder is of integral form? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Derivation_for_the_integral_form_of_the_remainder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From partial integration you know that
\begin{align}
f(x+h)&=f(x)+f'(x)h+\int_x^{x+h}(x+h-s)f''(s)\,ds
\end{align}
Now
$$
\int_x^{x+h}(x+h-s)\,ds=\frac12h^2
$$
so that adding a zero we get
\begin{align}
f(x+h)&=f(x)+f'(x)h+\frac12f''(x)h^2+\int_x^{x+h}(x+h-s)(f''(s)-f''(x))\,ds.
\end{align}
It is not clear where the different constants in the given formula come from. For functions with $f''(x)=0$ they give a visibly wrong result.

---

Now if you know that $|f''(x)-f''(y)|\le M|x-y|$, then (using $s=x+th$)
$$
\left|\int_x^{x+h}(x+h-s)(f''(s)-f''(x))\,ds\right|\le M\int_x^{x+h}(x+h-s)(s-x)\,ds
=Mh^3\int_0^1(1-t)t\,dt=\frac16Mh^3.
$$
If you insert this into the error estimate formula, you get $\frac16Mh^2$ as bound.

Comment: Could you take a look at the edit I made to the post?

Comment: Added comment on how you still get 1/6 as factor.